# Can´t make prediction with code trained model

Tags: c#, tensorflow, .net-6.0, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

**System Information:**

- Windows 10
- ML.NET Version: ML.NET v1.7.1
- .NET Version: .NET 6.0

**Bug description**
When I tried to get a prediction from a new trained model, the error

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Could not find input column 'ImagePath'
Parameter name: inputSchema'
```

**Expected behavior**
The final model should be saved & used for prediction.

**Code Snippets**
[Model Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb08x.png):

```
     public static void Run()
        {
            MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

            var model = GenerateModel(mlContext);
        }

        private static ITransformer GenerateModel(MLContext mlContext)
        {
            IEstimator<ITransformer> pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.LoadImages(outputColumnName: "input", imageFolder: _imagesFolder, inputColumnName: nameof(ImageData.ImagePath))
                // The image transforms transform the images into the model's expected format.
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(outputColumnName: "input", imageWidth: InceptionSettings.ImageWidth, imageHeight: InceptionSettings.ImageHeight, inputColumnName: "input"))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(outputColumnName: "input", interleavePixelColors: InceptionSettings.ChannelsLast, offsetImage: InceptionSettings.Mean))
                .Append(mlContext.Model.LoadTensorFlowModel(_inceptionTensorFlowModel).
                    ScoreTensorFlowModel(outputColumnNames: new[] { "softmax2_pre_activation" }, inputColumnNames: new[] { "input" }, addBatchDimensionInput: true))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(outputColumnName: "LabelKey", inputColumnName: "Label"))
                .Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.LbfgsMaximumEntropy(labelColumnName: "LabelKey", featureColumnName: "softmax2_pre_activation"))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabelValue", "PredictedLabel"))
                .AppendCacheCheckpoint(mlContext);

            IEnumerable<ImageData> temp = LoadImagesFromDirectory(folder: _imagesFolder, useFolderNameAsLabel: true);
            IDataView trainingData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(temp);

            ITransformer createdModel = pipeline.Fit(trainingData);

            mlContext.Model.Save(createdModel, trainingData.Schema, "FaceModel.zip");
            return createdModel;
        }
```

[Model Prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa30C.png):

```
private static PredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput> CreatePredictEngine()
            {
                var mlContext = new MLContext();
                ITransformer mlModel = mlContext.Model.Load(MLNetModelPath, out var _);
                return mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput>(mlModel);
            }
```

The two methods get called after each other, the existing FaceModel.zip will be replaced at the end of the first method. 2nd is working with a "non code trained" model, made with the vs model creator.

**Additional context**
GitHub Repository: https://github.com/paul1610/csharp-faceid

Comment: You seem to be using some bug report template, that is not used here, you need to explain the problem and put code in your question, not as external links.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Sorry, I added the important snippets

Comment: Same thing, two lines from a backtrace is not useful, there is no contex to relate it to your code. And please never put code as images! only as text.